# How do test Smart TV Alliance SDK app on Toshiba Device

Tags: html, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I've try to deploy and test an app made with the Smart TV Alliance SDK on an Toshiba Smart TV (32L4363D), but I can not find any informations on how to deploy apps for Toshiba devices. Only hint that I found on SAT-Page was an email-adress (contact@toshibaplaces.com), but no response yet.

I also can't find any developer-sites from Toshiba like on LG or Samsung.

Can someone help me, or tell me how to deploy/test apps on such devices ?

Greetings

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is a rather broad question for this site.

Comment: And why? I just want to know how to get the app on the TV, nothing more ;)

Comment: @user2979067 , have you solved this?

Comment: No, sorry for this. At the moment its only possible in cooperation with Toshiba, like STeN mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the proper tests on Toshiba CloudTV you need to have created the private space (similar to Sony BRAVIA), which you can do with close cooperation with Toshiba representatives.
BR
STeN

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for the Smart TV Alliance you can ask the QA team for instructions on how to get your app running on the member platforms. You can contact them via the website. https://developers.smarttv-alliance.org/contact